# Ruby undefined helper method

Tags: ruby

I am writing a simple ruby script.  I want a help message to be displayed when the script is run.

```
def myClass
    def help
        puts "Help message"
    end

    (...other methods...)

    help
    # main loop
    (...rest of script...)
end
```

When I run it, I get "undefined local variable or method 'help' for myClass:Class (NameError)".  Why doesn't ruby see my help method?  Did ruby lose it?  It's already defined!  I can't define it any further!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to define a class method, what you have there is an instance method.

```
class MyClass   
  def self.help
    puts "help"   
   end

  help

end
```

To clarify a bit

```
class MyClass
  def self.my_class_method
    puts 'class method'
  end

  def my_instance_method
    puts 'instance method'
  end
end

# class methods are called on teh class itself
MyClass.my_class_method

# instances methods are available on instances of the class
obj = MyClass.new
obj.my_instance_method
```

Comment: Thank you!  Can't believe I couldn't find that.